# C stack/scope, variable's lifetime after functions ends

Tags: c, stack

```
void someFunc()
{
    int stackInt = 4;

    someOtherFunc(&stackInt);
}
```

Is it the case that stackInt's address space could be reallocated after someFunc ends, making it unsafe to assume that the value passed to someOtherFunc represents the stackInt variable with value 4 that was passed to it? In other words, should I avoid passing stack variables around by address and expecting them to still be alive after the function they were initialised in has ended?

Comment: Somebody correct me if I am wrong, but isn't it safe to pass address of `stackInt` to `someOtherFunc`? The space will be reallocated only after someFunc has returned - which happens only after someOtherFunc is returned. The issue is only with returning the address of stack variables. Thus, if you return `&stackInt` from `someFunc` you're inviting trouble - otherwise you're safe.

Comment: You're generally right, but you can imagine code where someOtherFunc squirrels away that pointer somewhere (eg. a global variable) such that there's a reference to it even after someOtherFunc returns. This is where you have problems.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, definitely.

You don't have to avoid passing stack-allocated variables by reference/pointer altogether, though, just *storing* pointers or references to stack-allocated variables.

Answer (score 1):

After `someFunc()` returns and another function is called, the space that was used for `stackInt` will be used for some other variable in the new function.  Therefore, the function `someOtherFunc()` cannot safely assume that if it keeps a copy of the pointer it is passed, that pointer will remain valid.  If it stashes a copy of the value that was pointed at, that is fine.

So, although it is fine to pass stack variables around by address (so, for example `someOtherFunc()` could modify the value of `stackInt` and, if there was code in `someFunc()` that accessed it after the call, the value might not be 4 still), it is not safe to store the pointer and expect it to point to anywhere valid after `someFunc()` returns.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is absolutely fine to pass stack variables as parameters in all possible ways
2. The stack allocated variables will be overwritten only when the function declaring those variables is completed its execution.

So until you return from someFunc() there is no harm to stackInt.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't spawn new thread from someOtherFunc and use stackInt there, this will work.